# SDN4: Tests failing with latest snapshot

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4

I'm getting the following exception with tests:

```
org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.support.GraphRepositoryFactoryBean]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.support.GraphRepositoryFactoryBean.<init>()
```

Force updated dependencies.

SDN version: 4.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT
Neo4j version: 2.2.5 (getting same error with 2.2.4)
OGM: 1.1.2-SNAPSHOT

```
...
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>neo4j-ogm</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>neo4j-kernel</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.5</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.neo4j.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>neo4j-server</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.5</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <type>test-jar</type>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>neo4j-ogm</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <type>test-jar</type>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.neo4j.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>neo4j-harness</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.5</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

This only happens with tests.

Are there any changes in dependencies or configuration?

Thanks.

Comment: Please force an update with mvn -U and let me know if it still fails (with dependencies included)

Comment: I did force update before running the tests. I've included the dependencies now. Thanks.

Comment: The snapshot version is 4.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT but you seem to be using something else- 4.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT. Have you installed this locally after changing it? Can you delete org/springframework/data/neo4j from your local maven repo and try once more?

Comment: Sorry Luanne I am indeed using 4.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT but accidentally wrote "4.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT" in the question.

Comment: Your dependencies work for me. Do you have a project I can look at? Or mail the pom.xml to luanne at graphaware dot com please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else running into this issue, make sure your `@ComponentScan` excludes domain and repository packages.